# Angular Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I get the following error Error: [ngRepeat:dupes].

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
        <td>{{row.string}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

After looking through this site I saw a solution, use track by index: track by $index
The error is now gone but I don't get any data displayed.
As you can see below I tried a few ways to output data but this does not work.
Can anyone see my error?

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data track by $index">
        <td>{{row.id}}{{$index.id}}{{$index.row.id}}{{$index[id]}}{{$index[row.id]}}</td>
        <td>{{row.string}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my function:

```
$scope.displayString = function(){
        $http.get('/angular/all')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.data = data
        })
    }
```

And the data coming out of /angular/all
array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["string"]=> string(5) "vdfdf" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["string"]=> string(4) "dfgh" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["string"]=> string(4) "dfgh" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["string"]=> string(3) "963" } }

Comment: Please share your $scope.data

Comment: What is `$index.id`, `$index[row.id]` ? $index is a number, unless you created an object with key "$index".
`track by $index` should had  resolve your problem. Try to output just `{{row}}` to see what you got there...

Comment: Fixed it, forgot to use json_encode...